# 20 threads uses same amount of data as 10

Tags: python, multithreading, http, for-loop, beautifulsoup

so i have this code:

```
amplifier = input("Enter an amount of amplifiers: ")


def threads():
    for id in assetids:
        x = threading.Thread(target=check_price, args=[id])
        x.start()

for i in range(0, int(amplifier)):
    y = threading.Thread(target=threads)
    y.start()
```

when i try it it and i capture network it uses same amount of network percentage / mbps as lesser threads like 100 threads is same amount as 10
does anyone know what causes this?
also if this info is needed the threads does a for loop:
for i in range(sys.maxsize**10):
try:

in the for loop it makes a http request
capturing a html element and then returning it and printing it

Answer (score 0):

It's called *the law of diminishing returns*. Basically it says that there's a limit to everything and that you cannot reach inifinite speed. When you maximize the usage of one resource (in your case, CPU), you eventually hit the bottleneck of another resource.

In this case, the answer lies in whatever the `check_price` function is doing. Assuming your OS is doing a decent job, the bottleneck could be network bandwidth, disk bandwidth or synchronization overhead.